# Signals python threads asynchronous

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, signals, nonblocking

I have a main thread, which I want non-blocking, (it includes a PyQt5 GUI, I can not use join)

From this thread, I spawn a child thread performing an action.

I want to start an other action from the main thread when the child thread is finished.

I guess I have to generate a signal form the child when it is done and catch it in the main.
Is there a snippet showing the proper way to implement this?

Comment: I don't know what's your GUI Framework. If you are using PySide2, please try `new_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()`

Comment: I edited the question: PyQt5. I thought it was independant from the gui framework used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a built-in signal called finished, so you can connect it to your process method:

```
class NewThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def run(self):
        pass

class MainWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def after_thread_done(self):
        pass

    def __init__(self):
        self.thread = NewThread()
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.after_thread_done)
```

If you want to emit signal by hand, you can define a new signal:

```
class NewThread(QtCore.QThread):
    new_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def run(self):
        ...
        self.new_signal.emit()
        ...
```

Then connect it to your process method through the same codes.

If you want to define signals in MainWidget, you can pass main_widget as thread's parent.

```
class NewThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def run(self):
        ...
        self.parent().signal.emit()
        ...

class MainWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    new_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def after_thread_done(self):
        print("done")

    def __init__(self):
        self.new_signal.connect(self.after_thread_done)
        self.thread = NewThread(self)
        self.thread.start()
```

Comment: Yes, better by hand, since I am using `threading.Thread` and and it is called in a sub class.

But don't you have to create the signal in the `MainWidget` to connect it to `after_thread_done(self):` and then transmit it to the thread?

Comment: @RémiBaudoux Sorry my English is not so good so it's hard to understand disjunctive question. I think you should not transmit a signal from main widget to sub thread. If your signal and slot stay in the same thread, the connect type is `DirectConnection`. If your signal and slot stay in different threads, the connect type is `QueuedConnection`. I'm not pretty sure what do you want to do, so you'd better to test these two ways, and choose which one is better for you. Or you can specify the connect type as the second param `signal.connect(self.after_thread_done, Qt.QueuedConnection)`

Comment: @RémiBaudoux I see your idea. But I suggest you pass `MainWidget` as thread's parent. So you can use `self.parent().new_signal.emit()`. And you should use `self.thread.start()` instead of `self.thread.run()`. You should know what's the difference.